# how to specify grid-template with jss

Tags: css, css-grid, jss

Take a look at this example from [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#article-header-id-15):

```css
.container {
  grid-template:
    [row1-start] "header header header" 25px [row1-end]
    [row2-start] "footer footer footer" 25px [row2-end]
    / auto 50px auto;
}
```

How can I reproduce this with [jss](http://cssinjs.org/json-api?v=v9.8.1)?

Comment: Maybe take a look at how material-ui framework implemented their grid system : https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Grid/Grid.js

Comment: Old comment but React Material UI is actually using flex for their grid system, that wouldn't be helpful here.

Answer (score 13):

In your javascript, you can add it like this

```
import injectSheet from 'react-jss'
....
const MyComponent = ({ classes, children }) => (
  <div className={classes.container}>
    {children}
  </div>
)
...
export default injectSheet({
    container: {
     gridTemplateAreas: `
          "header header header"
          "sidebar main main"
          "footer footer footer"
        `,
    }
})(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer is going to be a little dirty.
But you know JSS has the ability similar to CSS.

If the CSS property you're looking for is named [`grid-template-columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns), then you can simply use `gridTemplateColumns`.

Let's just do an example.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: '100px 100px 100px';
}
```

In JSX, you can do something like..

```
const Grid = (props) => {
  const style = {
    display: 'grid',
    gridTemplateColumns: [1,2,3].map(i => '100px').join(' ')
  }
  return <div style={style}></div>
}
```

Now above is a dirty code sample. If you want to neat it a little bit, it could be better of course! Like putting it in a `useState` and changing it just when it needed to be.

**But the point is simple.** If you want to use a CSS property, you can just replace the CSS property name with a camelCase name convention and you will be fine.

Check out styling in React's documentation to learn more. [React DOM Element Style](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)

Comment: `grid-template-columns` is not the property I was looking for. That's quite something else  than the `grid-template` property I wanted to use.

Comment: @Vegar Yes, thanks for pointing that out! But I'm aware of it. I'm just providing samples of a similar problem that I just mentioned in my answer. If you want to use a CSS property, you can just replace the CSS property name with a camelCase name convention and you will be fine.

Comment: I just happened to look for a certain solution to my problem with CSS Grid, and this was just part of it.